# dynamic generating variable in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming

My code need to dynamic generating list according to my textbox value.
For example, if my textbox value is 4,then I can define list1 ,list2 ,list3 ,list4 in my program. To now, I can only change the textbox value and list in the sametime.
So, my problem is can I dynamic generating list according to a given value?

This is my code

```
public List<int> L0 = new List<int>();
public List<int> L1 = new List<int>();
public List<int> L2 = new List<int>();
```

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Why cant you make use of Lists? they are dynamic in size for a reason.

Comment: if its a list why cant you increase its items?? you can create a list of list

Comment: public List<int> L0 = new List<int>();public List<int> L1 = new List<int>();public List<int> L2 = new List<int>();    This is my code. I define them by hand, my goal is to define them dynamic. Is there a good way? I am not very familiar with C# characteristic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for lists. Lists are dynamic in size. You can increase the size as and when needed. Go through this MSDN article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx

```
List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>();

int NoOfItems = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);

for(int i=0;i<NoOfItems;i++)
{
   myList.Add(new List<int>();)
}
```

Comment: OK, I see. A list in list. Use myList[0] to quote the first List<int>,right?This seems great.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what I *guess* you're trying to do (not very detailed question to be honest. Assuming your textbox containing the number of lists you want to create is called `txtListCount`:

```
int count = int.Parse(txtListCount.Text); //convert text in the textbox to number
List<List<int>> myLists = new List<List<int>>(); //container for your lists
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        myLists.Add(new List<int>()); //create lists dynamically
    }
//myLists contains all your lists
```